# create unique index with function in hsqldb / liquibase

Tags: postgresql, hsqldb, liquibase

Is there a way to use function index in  hsqldb?

I tried those 4:

```
<column name="LOWER(name)"/>
<column name="LCASE(name)"/>
<column name="LOWER(name)" computed="true"/>
<column name="LCASE(name)" computed="true"/>
```

Inside my createIndex changeset:

```
<changeSet author="dgt" id="unique-postgres" dbms="hsqldb">
    <createIndex indexName="lower_case_index" tableName="users" unique="true">
        <column name="LOWER(name)" computed="true"/>
    </createIndex>
```

In documentation I noticed that hsqldb got: LOWER and LCASE built in function, but any of those do not work for me.

Every single time I've got an error:

> Reason: liquibase.exception.DatabaseException: unexpected token: (
>   required: ) [Failed SQL: CREATE UNIQUE INDEX PUBLIC.lower_case_index
>   ON PUBLIC.users(LOWER(name))]

I know about a solution that I can change column type from VARCHAR to VARCHAR_IGNORECASE, but it's not a case for me, because I need a solution to work on both db: hsqldb and postgres.

My ideal solution should look like this:

```
<changeSet author="dgt" id="users-unique-index-postgres" dbms="hsqldb">
    <createIndex indexName="name_index" tableName="users" unique="true">
        <column name="LOWER(name)" computed="true"/>
    </createIndex>
</changeSet>
<changeSet author="dgt" id="users-unique-index-hsqldb" dbms="postgresql">
    <createIndex indexName="name_index" tableName="users" unique="true">
        <column name="lower(name)" computed="true"/>
    </createIndex>
</changeSet>
```

But it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HSQLDB does not support function based indexes at all, so you need to find a different solution. You could e.g. define the column as `varchar_ignorecase` instead of `varchar` and then create a "normal" unique index on that column.

You can keep a single table definition by using properties.

That could look like this:

```
<changeSet author="dgt" id="create-users-table">
  <property name="users_name_type" value="varchar" dbms="postgresql"/>
  <property name="users_name_type" value="varchar_ignorecase" dbms="hsqldb"/>

  <createTable tableName="users">
    <column name="name" type="${users_name_type}">
      <constraints nullable="false"/>
    </column>
  </createTable>
</changeSet>


<changeSet author="dgt" id="users-unique-index-postgres" dbms="postgresql">
  <createIndex indexName="name_index" tableName="users" unique="true">
    <column name="lower(name)" computed="true"/>
  </createIndex>
</changeSet>

<changeSet author="dgt" id="users-unique-index-hsqldb" dbms="hsqldb">
  <createIndex indexName="name_index" tableName="users" unique="true">
    <column name="name"/>
  </createIndex>
</changeSet>
```

Comment: check this one: https://liquibase.jira.com/browse/CORE-2179 and another one: https://liquibase.jira.com/browse/CORE-2107.  You're sure there is no support for creating function based indexes?

Comment: @degath: ah, thanks I wasn't aware of that. But it doesn't change the approach for HSQLDB

Comment: So it seems like I can do it like in my example about postgres but still need to do it with varchar ignorecase for hsqldb?

Comment: @degath: correct (or you submit a patch for HSQLDB to support function based indexes)

Comment: I've got last question.  What is the reason to leave index for hsqldb? I can delete it now and it will work quite same.

Comment: @degath: no it will not work the same. If you leave out the unique index you can create two users with the same name which is apparently something you want to prevent

Comment: Belive or not. I actually deleted unique index for hsqldb. Adding just VARCHAR_IGNORECASE makes not possible to add for example NAME and name.

Comment: @degath: then you have some kind of unique index or unique constraint on that column. Is it maybe defined as the primary key?

Comment: Yeah I have UniqueConstraint  on it :) Forget to mention that.

Comment: *"HSQLDB does not support function based indexes at all, so you need to find a different solution"* @degath and other readers i know this is old question and answer. HSQLDB 2.0 has a better option then this which is called generated columns which you can index.. i believe generated columns where supported around 2010 - 2012.. More or less `<column_name> GENERATED ALWAYS AS (UPPER(name))` in the create table or alter command then you  can simple index the column as normal.